# The array values to get displayed in new line in nodeJs

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have an array like below:

`var test = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I want to get it displayed like below with every value in new line. How to full fill this requirement?

### New format display

```
[
'a', 
'b', 
'c'
]
```

Comment: New format is as below                                                                                                                  [
"a",                                                                                                                                 
"b",
 "c"
 ],

Comment: what is your expected output. Not clear

Comment: new format looks like exactly old one

Comment: In double quotes?

Comment: To format this question properly, you need to put 2 spaces at the end of each line, you can't just press enter. See the sidebar titled "How to Edit".

Comment: Added code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what exactly want. Where do you want to display your output?
e.g.

```
test.map(function(a){console.log(a)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but if you're just looking to "pretty print" an array, you can use the following function.

```
var test = ['a', 'b', 'c']

function format(array){
    var newFormat = '[\r\n';
    array.forEach(function(element, index){
        newFormat += "'" + element + "'";
        if (index+1 === array.length) {
            newFormat += '\r\n';
        } else {
            newFormat += ',\r\n';
        }
    });
    newFormat += ']';
    return newFormat;
}

console.log(format(test));
```

Keep in mind though that what this function returns is **not** an array. It is a string.